# Live incremental counter with variables

Tags: javascript, php, html, counter

I'm trying to create a live counter that would display the number of words translated live. I would feed it the start year, the current time, the number of translated words per year, and this counter would display a live count by averaging how many words are translated per year. That way I don't have to create a fake time interval to update this counter.

I found this snippet online and I was thinking of editing it to fit my needs:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div.cont {
                position: relative;
                background-image: url(counter.gif);
                width:160px;
                height:110px;
                vertical-align:text-bottom;
            }
            div.cont div.ans {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0px;
                margin-bottom:15px;
                margin-left:7px;
                color:black;
                font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
                font-size: 15pt;
                line-height: normal;
            }
        </style>
        <?php
        $now=time();
        $start=mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 24, 2007);
        $carbonsaving=((($now - $start) * 0.0058774) + 130000);
        $format=round($carbonsaving, 2);
        // in this example
        // $now=a unix timestamp of this very second
        // $start is the date that you want the counter to start from sent over
        //as a unix timestamp
        // $carbonsaving is the calculation that you want to perform to get
        //your base figure
        // i.e. total saving=( (date now - start date)* growth rate) + base rate
        // this gives us the starting saving all that needs to be done is increment it with javascript
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // we need to import our server side variable into javascript to let it increment live
            var car = <? php print($format); ?> ;
            var rou

                function incs() {
                    car = car + 0.01;
                    rou = Math.round(car * 100) / 100
                    document.getElementById("carb").innerHTML = rou;
                }
                // what function incs does is take car and adds 0.01 to it
                //rou rounds the figure to 2 dp
                //the document.getElementById("carb") can refer to a <p> tag //<span> or whatever and just says with .innerHTML=rou; that the //value between the  results of rou
        </script>
    </head>
    <!-- body onload setInterval tells the page to load our javascript function and repeat it by every x microseconds, so this repeats every 2 seconds //-->

    <body onload="setInterval('incs()', 2000)">
        <div class="cont">
            <div class="ans"> <span id="carb">Calculating...</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could anyone help me do this, cause I'm too bad at PHP... thanks

Comment: Care to use some indentation?

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = <?php echo mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 24, 2007); ?>; // desired start time.
    // refer to [1] for mktime() 
function updateCounter(){
    $(function(){
        $( "#count" ).load( "count.php?stime="+start );
    });
}
```

It will take current amount of words from php and write into the id.

You can now set an interval to update it:

```
<body onload="setInterval('updateCounter()', 2000)">
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
    // I assume that you have the function that finds translated words per year.
    // It's not clear that what you want from server side and client site.
    // Update me, please. Then I will update for you.
    echo $counter->get_current($_GET['stime']);
?>
```

[1] https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: Thanks Melih! I actually dont have the function for word count; I was envisioning giving a variable the number of words per year (average over the last, say 10 years or whatever). That number I have, I'd just like to be able to update it later on if needed.

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to update. Do you want to update it for that year? E.g. in the end of the year. Or you want to update browsers screen for fresh values gotten from another source?

Comment: Sorry, I'll give you a precise example to illustrate: say I want to start my count on Jan 1 2004 (10 years ago to simplify). Assuming my number of words translated per year is 10,000, and assuming the time right now is Jan 1 2014 at midnight, the count displayed at this very moment would be 100,000. I took round numbers to simplify, but they could be anything and the count displayed at any point in time on my website would be an average of words translated between the start date and today.

Comment: One other example, can you explain what would happen in this situation: The start day is `Jan 1, 2004` at midnight, end day is   `May 30, 2014` (rounded, 150th day of the year) at midnight. Number of words translated per year is `10,000`. The thing I don't understand is if you have the number of words translated per year why are you looking for a function to find it? You already have it. What do you exactly want to find? I see you just multiplied `10.000` with `10` which is `2014-2004`.

Comment: So how would I go about writing this? it may just be a syntax problem on my end... or I plain and simple suck at maths lol

Comment: By the way, in your example it would display 105,000 - 10 years + half a year's worth of words translated. I hope that clarifies a little because I really dont know how to explain this any better!

Comment: You mean you want to calculate it in the php? Something like this may be? `$count = $totalDays/365 * $wordsPerYear` In here `$totalDays` is number of days past in interval between the given start date and now.

Comment: `$totalDays/365` needs some fine tune though.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I have a working solution now, with numbers that make sense (thank you for helping me figure out how to do this, I guess my maths skills are even below what I thought!):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Live Word Count</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .count {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 10%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
    $now = time();
    $start = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 01, 2004);
    $wordsPerYear = 1000;
    $totalDays = (($now - $start) / 86400); // number of a seconds in a day
    $count = $totalDays / 365 * $wordsPerYear;
    $count = round($count);
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var totalWords = <?php print($count); ?>;
        function updateCounter() {
            totalWords = totalWords + 1; // need to do something here to update to the real word count instead of incrementing by 1 each second
            document.getElementById("carb").innerHTML=totalWords; }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="setInterval('updateCounter()', 1000);">
    <div class="count">
            <span id="carb">
                Loading Word Count...
            </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I just need to be able to make this figure update "live" with the real value of words translated instead of a "fake" live incrementation with `setInterval('updateCounter()', 1000)`.

Would you be able to help me put this together? :)